# Transforming an XML file using XSL leaves gaps where unselected elements would be

Tags: xslt

When I run an XSL to select certain elements of an XML file, I am getting gaps in the generated output where non-selected elements would be.

e.g. if I were transforming the following to only get black cats:

```
<cats>
 <cat>
  <name>Steve</name>
  <color>black</color>
 </cat>
 <cat>
  <name>Tom</name>
  <color>tabby</color>
 </cat>
 <cat>
  <name>Archibald</name>
  <color>black</color>
 </cat>
</cats>
```

I might get this:

```
<cats>
 <cat>
  <name>Steve</name>
  <color>black</color>
 </cat>




 <cat>
  <name>Archibald</name>
  <color>black</color>
 </cat>
</cats>
```

Is this controllable in the XSL itself, or is it a 'feature' of the tool I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controllable in the XSL. You need to do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    ....

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It happens because in your XML, there are whitespace elements (e.g. line breaks, carriage returns) between `<cat>` and `<name>` and so on. These get matched by built-in templates for text nodes and output. The `<xsl:strip-space>` element removes insignificant whitespace from your input. You will then need to set `indent="yes"` in the `<xsl:output>` element to achieve the indenting you want.